How are called the fouls made with the sole? Translation of ‘planchazo’
Need help for an English equivalent of this action, I didn't find anything:

planchazo (also plancha)
Adelantamiento frontal de la suela del pie, que constituye una infracción en varios deportes.


???
A frontal stretching of the foot's sole that constitutes a foul in many sports.

My guess is that there isn't any term. If that's the case, how should we call that? A ‘sole’ foul?


There is "foot fault" in English ... maybe related?

Maybe. Is the term is specifically used for impacts with the sole?

Do you actually mean a flat sole, or specifically studs/cleats (sharp bits on the sole that can cause bad injuries)? What sports is it worse to hit someone with a flat sole than with a toe or heel?

I believe it is called a studs up tackle:

A studs up tackle is made when a player lunges into a tackle with a leg or both legs outstretched exposing the soles of their boots.
Wikipedia/Tackle(football move)

You can also describe it with the phrase studs showing/up. Cambridge defines the phrase as below with example sentences:

with the studs of your football boots pointing at a player's leg when you tackle them:

A sliding tackle with the studs up is illegal in most leagues. 
The young player slid in with studs showing on Miller.
He received a red card for a two-footed tackle with his studs showing.


